# I keep getting this MySQL error Incorrect prefix key #1089

Tags: mysql

This message showing when i try to create a table.

```
#1089 - Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys
```

This is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE `xyz`.`company_info` ( `c_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `cname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `ctitle` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , `cestab` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `cfounder` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `caddress` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL , `ccontact` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `cemail` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `cweb` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `clogo` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , `status` INT(10) NOT NULL , `created_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`(10))) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Use `mysql` tag if you have `query` related question.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`(10))
```

with:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`)
```

You already give the length when you define the field, you don't need to give it again in the primary key definition.